# KineticJS 4.6 no longer working in Chrome 29

Tags: google-chrome, kineticjs

I'm working on a project using KineticJS version 4.6 (currently the latest version), and since last night's Chrome update to Chrome 29, the Kinetic canvas is completely blank. While using the console, I am still able to detemine that the created objects, such as the Kinetic.Stage and Kinetic.Layer, still exist and are filled with correct data.

Afterwards, I tried loading the same page in Internet Explorer and Firefox, and they still work as intended, showing the canvas with the correct elements.

I have tried searching for people with similar issues, but I guess Chrome's update is too recent to show any results. Does anyone perhaps know if there is a way to fix it or if I should simply wait for either a KineticJS or a Chrome update?

**EDIT:** And now it suddenly works again after restarting Chrome. Hotfixed?

**EDIT2:** After a while it broke again, but restarting the browser seems to work

**EDIT3:** It is a bug in Chrome, acknowledged by the Chromium team in [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=278940). The thread states that the bug is definitely fixed in version 30, which is currently in beta. This fix may be merged in version 29 soon, but there is no definitive timetable for this.

Comment: What were you trying to do with KineticJS? some code, error from console log or network profile would be useful to determine where the bug is, as such your question cannot be answered

Comment: I'm not experiencing any problems with Kinetic 4.6 under Chrome29.  As Ani says, try to isolate a specific problem and get back with us.

Comment: I think it's a bug in the new Chrome... I experienced more issues on the new chrome (sound).

You could check this link which pin points to probably the same issue, and keep track of it:

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/584

Comment: We have exactly same issue. It's not just Kinetic, we see it also in other Canvas based applications.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem in Chrome 29.

In some cases a workaround is to tell your users to use Chrome Incognito mode to fix this issue.

A test to replicate the issue consistently is posted here:
https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/585

At present, the bug is not present in Chrome 30. (8/27/2013)

You should star this chromium issue:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=280153

Comment: The chromium issue you mentioned has been merged into another issue, it is a known bug and is definitely fixed in Chrome 30 onwards. They say that it will be fixed in Chrome 29 soon, but are unable to give a specific time.

Overarching Chromium issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=278940